# Customized autocompletion in UITextView

Tags: iphone, autocomplete, uitextview

I want to do the customized autocompletion for UITextView...

For example:

```
  If the user starts to type "Busines" I would like to suggest "Business1", "Business2", , so that the user can select any one of the 2 suggestions or choose to type a new one.
```

All the custom word suggestion will be in the array...

How can I achieve this ??

Is `completionsForPartialWordRange:inString:language:` something that I can use.. How can I pass the values in the array???

Comment: How are you loading your array?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
  - (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring 
{
    [autocomplete_array removeAllObjects];
    for(int i=0;i<[your_main_array count];i++)
    {
         NSString *curString = [your_main_array objectAtIndex:i];
         curString = [curString lowercaseString];
         substring = [substring lowercaseString];

         if ([curString rangeOfString:substring].location == NSNotFound) 
         {} 
         else 
         { 
             [autocomplete_array addObject:curString] 
         }  
    }
    [autocompletedisplayTableView reloadData];
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text 
{
    if( textView == your_TextView)
    {
        [your_TextView resignFirstResponder];
        autocompletedisplayTableView.hidden = NO;

        NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:your_TextView.text];
        substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
        return YES;
    }
}
```

your_main_array : will be your original array which you'll load from web service.
autocomplete_array : will be the array you'll get after the searching process is finished.

When user search you'll have to pass autocomplete_array to your `UITableView`